# Android Phone SD Card only shows folders no files in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows

When connecting an android phone to a PC and viewing the files in Windows Explorer there is an issue trying to view the files. When I try to view the files on the SD card it only shows the folders not the files. This does not occur on all of my PC's only one. What can I do to view the files on my SD card from an android phone connected by a USB?

Thank you in advance for any assistance